# Establecer un bucle que no de error cuando no haya un grupo para seleccionar

Tags: r, bucle-for, bucles

Estoy intentando sacar de forma aleatoria una muestra y he establecido un bucle para ello que me seleccione de cada grupo indicado x individuos por provincia, sexo y edad. Para ello, primero calculo la cantidad representativa de cada grupo y luego, con el bucle, selecciono la muestra de un panel. El problema es que hay ciertos grupos que no tienen, del panel de donde se saca, ningún individuo representativo y cuando llega a este me da error y se para el bucle con el siguiente error: `Error in slice_sample(): ! n must be positive`. Mi duda es si es posible indicar que cuando se encuentre un grupo que no tiene representación, pase al siguiente, sin que se pare.

El código que he utilizado hasta ahora es el siguiente:

**Calculo lo que corresponde a cada grupo por provincia, edad y sexo**

```
muestra <- 4000

cuotas <- datos.ine %>% mutate(total=porc*n_muestra/100)

cuotas <- cuotas %>% mutate(e18_28=porc*total[[51]]/100,
                             e25_34=porc*total[[52]]/100)

cuotas <- cuotas %>% mutate(h18_28=e18_28*porc[[53]]/100,
                             h25_34=e25_34*porc[[53]]/100,
                             m18_28=e18_28*porc[[54]]/100,
                             h25_34=e25_34*porc[[54]]/100,
```

**Atribuyo a targets lo que he calculado en cuotas y lo coloco en cuatro filas por provincia, sexo, edad y el total que necesito de cada grupo y lo ordeno todo por las tres primeras variables**

```
targets <- cuotas %>% pivot_longer(c("h18_28", "h25_34
                                      "m18_28" "m25_34"),
                                    names_to="grupo", values_to="total")

targets <- targets %>% separate(grupo, c("Sexo", "Edad"), sep=1)

targets <- targets %>% mutate(Sexo=case_when(Sexo=="h" ~ "Hombre",
                                           Sexo=="m" ~ "Mujer"))

targets<- targets %>% arrange(provincia, Sexo, Edad)
```

**Establezco:**

**1. Primero, un valor llamado n, que refleja el número de filas de nuestras sentencias.**

**2. Segundo, una lista vacía llamada *muestra_list*. En esta lista se irán guardando las bases de datos de cada grupo por el que segmentamos.**

**3. El bucle para que me coja la sentencias establecidas en targets del panel. Y que aquí es donde me da el error al no encontrar en el panel a mínimo un individuo de alguno de los grupos**

```
n = nrow(targets)
muestra_list <- list()

for(i in 1:n){
  muestra<- panel %>% filter(Provincia==targets$provincia[[i]], 
                             Sexo==targets$Sexo[[i]], 
                             Grupoedad==targets$Edad[[i]])
  
  cantidad <- ifelse(targets$total[[i]] > nrow(muestra), nrow(muestra), targets$total[[i]])
  muestra_list[[i]] <- slice_sample(muestra, n = cantidad)
}
```

Muchas gracias¡!

Comment: Esto `if (cantidad > 0) muestra_list[[i]] <- slice_sample(muestra, n = cantidad)` no es lo que buscas?

Answer (score 0):

Ya que estás utilizando pipes y `dpylr`, una solución tipo `tidy` es mejor que un bucle for.

Existen dos funciones que te pueden ayudar:

- `sample_frac`: muestrear aleatoriamente en función a una fracción del total (de 0 a 1)
- `sample_n`: muestrear aleatoriamente en función a una cantidad (puedes incluso incluir una función `ifelse` al interior).

Datos de muestra:

```
set.seed(123)

panel <- data.frame(Provincia = sample(month.name[1:3],
                                       1000,
                                       replace = T),
                    Sexo = sample(c('M','F'),
                                  1000,
                                  replace = T),
                    Edad = sample(c('18-30',
                                    '30-40',
                                    '40-50'),
                                  1000,
                                  replace = T))
```

Utilizando `sample_frac`(y separando el resultado del muestreo en diferentes tibbles para poder trabajarlas independientemente, si es que así lo deseas):

```
panel %>%
  group_by(Provincia,
           Sexo,
           Edad) %>% 
  sample_frac(0.75) %>% 
  group_split()
```

Utilizando `sample_n`:

```
panel %>%
  group_by(Provincia,
           Sexo,
           Edad) %>% 
  sample_n(ifelse(n() > 50,
                  45,
                  20))%>% 
  group_split()
```

Ahora, no sabemos el contenido de `targets`. Si difiere a `panel`, utiliza `left_join` o algo similar (en base al contenido del objeto) y luego sigue el procedimiento que aquí describo.

---

En base a la edición de la pregunta, considerando panel como:

```
panel <- data.frame(Provincia = sample(month.name[1:3],
                                       1000000,
                                       replace = T),
                    Sexo = sample(c('h',
                                    'm'),
                                  1000000,
                                  replace = T),
                    Edad = sample(c('18_28',
                                    '25_34'),
                                  1000000,
                                  replace = T))
```

Luego, en base a la pregunta (si es que un grupo en `targets` no está presente en `panel`), creé un objeto eliminando uno de las provincias:

```
muestra <- 4000

targets <- expand.grid(provincia = month.name[1:2],
                       Sexo = c('h',
                                'm'),
                       Edad = c('18_28',
                                '25_34'))

targets$total <- round(1000 + rnorm(n = nrow(targets),mean = 0,sd = 500))

targets$muestra_test <- TRUE
```

La función de la columna `muestra_test` es para luego filtrar la bbdd una vez es combinada con `targets`:

```
panel %>%
  left_join(targets,
            by = c('Provincia' = 'provincia',
                   'Sexo' = 'Sexo',
                   'Edad' = 'Edad')) %>% 
  filter(muestra_test) %>% 
  select(-total, -muestra_test) %>% 
  group_by(Provincia,
           Sexo,
           Edad) %>% 
  sample_n(ifelse(n() >= muestra,
                  muestra,
                  n()))
```

En este caso, el tamaño de la muestra está condicionado por la cantidad de observaciones de la combinación Provincia - Sexo - Edad. Si la cantidad de filas es menor a `muestra`, se extrae la cantidad de filas total en vez de el valor establecido en `muestra`. Eliminé las columna `total` que está presente en `targets` y la prueba lógica para filtrar para sacar todas las filas de `targets` de la muestra deseada.

Para finalizar, puedes utilizar este objeto como una bbdd única desagrupando con `ungroup` o separarlas por combinación con `group_split`

Comment: En targets lo que hay es la asignación de lo que debería haber de cada grupo por provincia, edad y sexo para que la muestra sea representativa. Y esto luego se utiliza para sacar de forma aleatoria la muestra de un panel. La cosa es que en este panel hay menos gente de la que corresponde para cada grupo y el error se produce cuando en el grupo directamente no hay ningún individuo y no se puede coger al menos 1.

Comment: Bueno, con `left_join` quedarían excluidos aquella combinación que existe en `targets` pero no en `panel`. Si cuelgas un set de datos podría expandir mi respuesta

Comment: Te he puesto todo el código explicado a ver si con eso lo entiendes bien. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Lea a ver si entendí. Complementé la respuesta